# What's wrong here? Checkboxes aren't working

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, hidden

I'm trying to make checkboxes to hide/show paragraphs, but for some reason, the paragraphs don't appear when I click the checkbox, here is the JavaScript code:

```
function showPara()
{
    document.getElementById("first").style.visibility=(document.formex.firstpara.checked) ? "block" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("second").style.visibility=(document.formex.secondpara.checked) ? "block" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("third").style.visibility=(document.formex.thirdpara.checked) ? "block" : "hidden";
    return true:
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<p id="first">This is a paragraph</p>
<p id="second">This is a paragraph</p>
<p id="third">This is a paragraph</p>

<form name="formex">
    <input type="checkbox" name="firstpara" onClick="showPara();"/>First Paragraph<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="secondpara" onClick="showPara();"/>Second Paragraph<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="thirdpara" onClick="showPara();"/>Third Paragrpah<br />
</form>
```

Comment: Your CSS is off. It's `display: block|none` (more or less) and `visibility: visible|hidden`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `visibility: block`, so `hidden` is not being altered.  Use `visibility: visible`.  You also have a syntax error in the function (`return true;` vs. `return true:`).

http://jsfiddle.net/frKXN/1/

Comment: +1 for spotting the syntax error. I was faster, but you actually found both errors :)

Answer (score 2):

The `visibility` CSS property can have two values: `hidden` or `visible`.

You are setting it to `block`, which doesn't work. You probably confused it with the `display` property, which can be set to `block`, `none` and a few other values.

Comment: Did you also corrected the syntax error Explosion Pills spotted? I tested your code on Firefox, with both errors corrected, and it works.